# Python, Store root password securely

Tags: python, security, passwords, pyinstaller

To ask my question I should tell you about my project.

So currently I am working on a local Password Manager in Python. To use the Password Manager you initially need to set up a Main Password and with that password we decode all of our stored passwords. The stored passwords are stored inside a .txt file, but they are not stored in plain text. They are decoded, therefore you cannot see the passwords directly. You can only see them if you have the Main Password.

Then I create a .exe file with my project. I am using Pyinstaller with the following command: `pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py`.

Afterwards I use WinRar to create an installer. I use the installer to install my Password Manager on other laptops without having to install python.

Now to my Problem:

I dont know how I can store my main password. I mean I cannot store it in plain text, because then you can directly decode all my passwords and I also cannot decode my Main Password to store it decoded, because for decoding my main password I need another password to decode it (this will result in a loop).

My Thoughts:
If you install my Password Manager and start it at first you need to set up your root password. I was wondering if I could then use this password to start my Program with this password (I mean giving it as a parameter and getting it inside my script with `os.getenv()`. But I dont know if this works.

I would appreciate it if someone got a good solution for my problem.

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Password managers don't typically store the master password as well, do they? I've never used a password manager. That seems strange to me. Isn't that the whole point, that you only have to remember one (master) password?

Comment: the point is that I need to authenticate the user. If i cannot store the main password i cannot check whether the user is allowed to see the other passwords

Comment: But why do you need to store it? I still don't understand. Can't you just use the master-password as a private key for your encryption scheme? I suppose there still wouldn't be a way to confirm that the password is correct, but that doesn't really matter - if they enter the wrong password, the decryption won't yield the correct decrypted passwords.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I want to not only use it by myself. I also want to share it to another compute where I dont want to code my hash of my password. It should be dynamic.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Sorry I don't have any suggestions.

Comment: No worries thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this would help in your situation, but since you are controlling both the host and clients in this case, perhaps you can implement a one-time password (OTP) setup.  There is a python module called PyOTP that may help.  Haven't actually used it, but it may offer a solution to your issue (Docs are here: [PyOTP documentation](https://pyotp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Comment: Thank you @Fubar! Can you explain in more detail what your idea is. I didnt quite get it.

Comment: Basically it boils down to "Run bit on host to generate a secret code -> communicate to code to client -> receive on client -> generate a password on client -> enter password on host -> host verifies or denies".  Using  access control on the host side, you can control who can run the host piece to generate secrets.  Since the password is never the right password except during a 30 second window, if you don't have access to the host piece it makes it tough to break into.